# Parse var in json string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a  problem to parse a variable from a json string. The variable (trackingID)is a dynamic url parameter for clicky goal tracking and it changes dynamically, depending on visitor source.

```
var trackingID = window.location.search.substring(1);
clicky_custom.goal = { name: 'project-name - trackingID' };
```

Comment: I honestly can't figure out what you mean. Can you please edit the question and provide examples of different input sets and expected output? (Also, there's no JSON in your code... Do you mean that the object shown is the result of JSON parsing?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clicky_custom.goal = { name: 'project-name - ' + trackingID };
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an appropriate solution for your case

```
var trackingID = req.query.trackingID;  //Get trackingID from query string

if(typeof trackingID != 'undefined'){

      var name = {projectName: ''};

      name.projectName = 'project-name ' + trackingID;

      clicky_custom.goal = name
}
```